# How to use the SharePoint default Navigation with drop down menu for showing the sub sites in custom master page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, master-page, custom-masterpage

I created a custom master page,and I need to use the default SharePoint navigation with drop down menu,so I configured the Top bar Navigation from

- Site setting > Navigation > (structured navigation for showing subsites only),

It's working fine with Seattle and Oslo master page,But it's not working with my custom master page.

Comment: This is a SharePoint 2013 I'm right ? so are you copy the navigation snippet to your master page ?

Comment: Yaa Qassas its SharePoint 2013,I copied the snippet of top navigation,but I can't see the Dropdown menu  in navigation.

Comment: make sure that it has not a custom style or any script related to top navigation in your code ?

Comment: First of all thanks for your response, I used bootstrap framework for making its responsive,and I also checked after removing the bootstrap classes ,Then also its not working